# ThreeJS black screen - no console errors

Tags: three.js

Trying to learn three.js and I can only manage to see a black screen while trying to replicate a three.js example. I tried adding hemisphere lights and it did not change anything. If anyone can point me in the right direction I'd be so happy

```
        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
        renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
        renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
        renderer.toneMappingExposure = 0.8;
        renderer.outputEncoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding
        container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

        //var pmremGenerator = new THREE.PMREMGenerator( renderer );
        //pmremGenerator.compileEquirectangularShader();

        controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement );
        controls.addEventListener( 'change', render ); //use if no anim loop
        controls.minDistance = 2;
        controls.maxDistance = 10
        controls.target.set( 0, 0, - 0.2 );
        controls.update();

        window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

    }

    function.onWindowResize() {

        camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
        camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

        renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

        render();

    }


    function render() {

        renderer.render( scene, camera );

    }

    </script>

</body>
```

I Really don't know what to do as I'm just starting out. I'm running locally on my home comp so it should not be an issue regarding that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a moment to [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and visit the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), especially [`How do I ask a good question?`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [`How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Regarding your question, please take a look at the code behind [the three.js examples](https://threejs.org/examples/). Your code is missing a lot of vital pieces, like where you define your scene, camera, lights, and meshes.